# How to return a specific type from a generic method?

Tags: c#, generics, methods, parameters

I am trying to mock a utility generic class but I'm not having success in returning a specific type from a method that uses generics. My implementation below is not working, the compiler is complaining. Can someone help cast and return the specific object I need?

```
public HttpResponse<TResponse> SubmitRequest<TResponse>(string serviceUri, HttpVerbEnum httpVerb, HttpContentTypeEnum contentType, NameValueCollection header)
{
    string RawResponse = "";
    HttpResponse<CreateSaleResponse> Response = new HttpResponse<CreateSaleResponse>(new CreateSaleResponse(), RawResponse, System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Created);
    return Response;
}
```

Comment: `the compiler is complaining` and you didn't add the compiler error, because you'd like us to guess?

Comment: **Pro Tip** : Compiler errors are important, they are included by the CLR to alert wary travellers of incorrect syntax. Very few programmers knoq the language inside and out, so we learn to rely on such errors to give us clues to whats wrong, they are even searchable and have links to common problems. As someone who is looking at your problem without the benefit of knowing what you are doing or sitting in front of your computer, we rely on these errors even more. please modify your question to include the error in future

Answer (score 0):

Doing what you're currently doing is probably tossing out a *"cannot implicitly convert type"* error. If you're going to return one specific type, then that method doesn't need to support generics.

What you seem to want is something like this, that uses the type you specify:

```
public HttpResponse<TResponse> SubmitRequest<TResponse>(string serviceUri, HttpVerbEnum httpVerb, HttpContentTypeEnum contentType, NameValueCollection header)
{
    string RawResponse = "";
    HttpResponse<TResponse> Response = new HttpResponse<TResponse>(new TResponse(), RawResponse, System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Created);
    return Response;
}
```

You pass in the type when you call the method:

```
var response = SubmitRequest<SomeAppropriateType>(...);  // pass in your parameter values
```

As far as how to mock this (for testing purposes?), that depends on the mock library you're using.